# Mysql. Вложенный запрос на выборку уникальных полей по трем полям

Tags: mysql

Не могу понять почему мускул не находит столбец по алиасу во вложенном запросе.

```
select projects.id as pid, 
       projects.name as `name`, 
       projects.created_at as created_at, 
       ( select count(*) 
         from domains 
         where exists ( select * 
                        from project_items 
                        where erased = 0 
                          and domains.id = project_items.domain_id 
                          and exists ( select * 
                                       from projects 
                                       where project_items.project_id = projects.id 
                                         and id = pid
                                     )
                       )
       ) as domains_count, 
       ( select count(*) 
         from ( SELECT count(pi.location_id) 
                       FROM project_items AS pi
                       JOIN projects AS pr 
                              ON pr.id = pi.project_id 
                             AND pr.id = pid
                       JOIN users AS u 
                              ON u.id = pr.user_id 
                             AND u.id = 3 
                       WHERE pi.erased = 0
                       GROUP BY pi.location_id, 
                                pi.keyword_id, 
                                pi.country_id
               ) as c
       ) as keywords_count
 from `projects` 
 where `erased` = 0 
   and `user_id` = 3
```

вот ошибка которую дропает мускул:

> Unknown column 'pid' in 'on clause'

Comment: *Unknown column* Запомните накрепко - если в запросе используется более одной таблицы (даже если это две копии одной таблицы), следует указывать алиас таблицы для КАЖДОГО поля, вне зависимости от степени очевидности. А также каждой копии одноимённой таблицы присваивайте уникальный в пределах запроса алиас - опять же  вне зависимости от области видимости и степени очевидности. Тогда и таких дурацких ситуаций не будет...

Comment: Дополнительно - поле выходного набора получает имя только после выполнения GROUP BY (при его отсутствии - после той точки, где его следовало бы разместить). До этой точки использовать алиас поля выходного набора нельзя - его не существует.

Answer (score 0):

```
select projects.id as pid,
```

Если я правильно увидел, то в верхнем select'e не указан параметр from  соответственно он не понимает что за поле pid (а если быть точнее он не знает что за поле projects.id

Comment: from `projects`  он есть в конце запроса, до этого блока идут вложенные запросы.